# How to prove that ⊢A∨B implies ⊢A or ⊢B

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The formal system can be taken to be any formulation of the standard propositional calculus. With soundness and completeness at hand, ⊢A∨B⇒⊨A∨B⇒[⊨A or ⊨B]⇒[⊢A or ⊢B]. I want to know how to prove this using only syntactical concepts and whether there is a general algorithm that converts a proof of ⊢A∨B into a proof of A or a proof of B. I guess there should be one, for if either A or B must be provable, then enumerate all proofs in an appropriate order until one is found.

Thanks.

Comment: In classical propositional logic we have $\vdash p \vee \neg p$, while $\not\vdash p$ and $\not\vdash\neg p$, where $p$ is a propositional variable.

Comment: @random-jack Good. I know where I was mistaken now. Thank you.

Comment: It might be interesting to note that this property, which is called the disjunction property, holds in many constructive logics.

Comment: @RandomJack Also, for any formula 'f', which is not a contradiction, nor a tautology, $\not$$\vdash$f and $\not$$\vdash$$\lnot$f.

Comment: In natural deduction, if you prove a statement of the form $A \lor B$, and if for every axiom of the form $x \lor y$ you knew which $x$ or $y$ was the constructable proposition, then you know which of $A \lor B$ is the constructable proposition.  It can be established inductively, as none of the inferences lose that information.

Comment: See [Disjunction property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_and_existence_properties) and related [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2000978/proof-of-the-disjunction-property).